# Code analysis not working after ReSharper uninstall

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper, code-analysis

I uninstalled ReSharper 6 recently. Now, if I look at any code analysis ruleset it won't display any other info than the ID (e.g. CA1001). The name and all other infos are shown as "unknown" and the analsis will fail saying that the rulesets are not comapitble.

I looked in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets and found the *.ruleset-Files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please repair the VS installation
After that, please reset settings to their defaults in "Tools | Import and export settings".

Thank you.

Alex Berezoutsky, ReSharper Support Engineer @ JetBrains

Comment: I'll try that out when I have my VS-install-medium. Is'nt it avoidable to handle the uninstall that way? Seems very "dirty" to me.